# ADT 22.2 New App Wizard: Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I found some answers to that issue but none worked for me. When getting the last screen in a new project creation, I'm getting the next message:

> Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin

The required version is empty (in some cases appears as 8). The installed version is 18.

I already tried many of the solutions I found here, like:

- Run the SDK manager as administrator
- Run Eclipse as administrator
- Re-install the support components from the SDK extra folder and then restart Eclipse,

None of these didn't work for me.

Is there another solution?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Android eclipse plugin, eclipse help check for updates.....

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845017/unsupported-template-dependency-upgrade-your-android-eclipse-plugin-sdk-tools-v

Comment: We're working on a fix and should have an updated adt/tools soon.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Update 2:** Now (2013-09-19T17:00:00Z) there's an *ADT 22.2.1* and *Tools 22.2.1* updates available that fix this issue:

> - Use Eclipse > Help > Check for Updates to get ADT 22.2.1
> - Use SDK Manager to get Tools 22.2.1
>
> You need both parts to fix the issue. The ADT bundle and the installer package on http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html have been updated too.

(From [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149#c109))

---

**Update**: The [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149) now has a [response](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149#c55) with fixed template files attached and the following comments:

> This one is my bad. I was in the middle of changing the dependency system used by the templates and a transient state got picked up into this tools build. The templates have settled in the AOSP master branch.
>
> I've attached a snapshot of the current Activities templates. Replacing your sdk/tools/templates/activities folder with the contents of this zip should resolve this issue.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience.

My older workaround below.

---

Workaround to the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149):

For **Blank Activity**:

1. Edit `<sdk>/tools/templates/activities/BlankActivity/template.xml`
2. Comment out the dependency:

   ```
   <!--<dependency name="appcompat" version="v7" />-->
   ```

For **Master/Detail Flow**:

1. Edit `<sdk>/tools/templates/activities/MasterDetailFlow/template.xml`
2. Comment out the dependencies:

   ```
   <!--<dependency name="support" version="v4" />
   <dependency name="android-support-v4" revision="8" />-->
   ```

**Finally:**

- Restart Eclipse

If needed, copy `android-support-v4.jar` from `<sdk>/extras/support/v4` to your `libs`.

Comment: After applying this fix, I encountered a new problem (and fortunately found a solution): [Eclipse reports rendering library more recent than ADT plug-in](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18852983/145173).

Comment: Super, edit these 2 XML files solved the issue.                                                               Many Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4):

@Šantić A. Miroslav - I'm not sure why, but deleting the SDK tools does not downgrade to the previous version. The folder `<sdk>/tools` just disappeared and a *path not found error* occurred.

---

I tried to download from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-windows.zip, unzip it and replace it with the `<sdk>/tools` folder to **downgrade** the SDK tools, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. It happen when I upgraded the Android SDK Tools to Rev. 22.2. Downgrading to a older version will get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem the last couple of hours, and I resolved it... I downloaded the SDK (for my Mac) from the link below.

> [For Mac]
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-macosx.zip
>
> [For Windows] 
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-windows.zip
>
> [For Linux]
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-linux.zip

I went to Android installed directory --> tool and replaced all the content with the downloaded files.

I restarted Eclipse, executed *New Project*, and it's working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Please try my workaround:

1. Create a new project using command line

   - Notes: DO NOT create it in Eclipse's workspace, create it elsewhere e.g. `~/tmp/`
   - e.g. `android create project --target 1 --name MyAndroidApp --path ./MyAndroidAppProject --activity MyAndroidAppActivity --package com.example.myandroid`
2. Then in Eclipse, "**Import**" the project you've just created

Answer (score 0):

#### Working solution

I downloaded the adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729 from http://burnbit.com/torrent/251451/adt_bundle_windows_x86_64_20130729_zip. After I updated, I also got the same error as you got. Without updating, I created the project, so now it's running. So do this step. This error is coming because of a version mismatch. So do this step.

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the latest SDK version. Please downgrade to r_22. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your ADT plugin for it.The latest version of an Android SDK tool is 22.2.1 and for that you need ADT bundle 22.2.1.
Download link for it is 
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/Android-Development-Tools.shtml