# BUG in Android ADT-SDK-22.2

Tags: android, sdk, adt

Couldn't able to create new Android Project in the new upgraded SDK 22.2

It shows the following error..

Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin..

When this bug will be fixed??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues when create new android application project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlast the problem has been solved by replacing the existing activities folder with the new one, provided by the Project member from code.google!!

This is the path to navigate to the activities folder in SDK:

**android-sdks/tools/templates/activities**

Download the activities folder from http://relinjose.com/android/activities.zip

That's it!! U Are Done!!
Else, restart....

Answer (score 1):

You must upgrade Eclipse ADT here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 1):

This because new Update of ADT, and downgrading is the only solution for now while waiting Google fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the ADT 22 release. See the bug report and response by the developers [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149&q=unsupported%20template&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

Quick fix is to download and replace the contents of sdk/tools/templates/activities with [this](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=601490055000&name=activities.zip&token=i1jnjH60JXnnnFUq2ahN6n96sdA%3A1379459567094).

Comment: second link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your `sdk/tools/templates/activities` folder with the contents of this zip should resolve this issue.

Link: [Activities Zip](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=601490055000&name=activities.zip&token=tNG-jL5v1K1cnbgIbRyPgrXtRF8:1379484316034)

Answer (score 1):

Android/Google fixed this today a few hours ago with ADT 22.2.1. If you downgraded ADT like I did to avoid this bug, you should be able to update to ADT 22.2.1 now.

Source: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/bsRQ7RBjnot

> Android Developers originally shared:   We've just released ADT
>   22.2.1: an update to the Android SDK tools and the ADT plugin for Eclipse, to fix an important bug related to creating new projects.