# 'Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin' with SDK Tools v22

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I recently upgraded my Android SDK Tools to version 22. But whenever I am trying to create a new project in Eclipse, I get an error message:

> Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does your dialog show blank in the 'Required Version' field, which is what I'm seeing? It would explain why the upgrade version on the dialog doesn't do anything.

Comment: The following link helped me evade the problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse/18849033#18849033

Answer (score 24):

Download from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-windows.zip, unzip it and replace the /tools folder with this one to downgrade the sdk tools. There's a bug in version 22.

For Mac http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-macosx.zip

For Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-linux.zip

Comment: This left me with an error saying ...tools/emulator not found, which went away when I copied 'emulator' from the 'bad' version of tools that I had moved out of the way. (OS X Mountain Lion by the way)

Comment: @user1681572 try again, it works for me on 10.7.5.

Comment: It's a *known* issue being worked at the moment. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149 for progress and workaround discussion.

Answer (score 6):

The project member posted [comment #55](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149#c55) that solves this issue without downloading the SDK tools. Just download the [activity templates](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=601490055000&name=activities.zip&token=qu6pDWoA3LnqN69bBiikSguYIW8:1379510691437) and replace the `sdk/tools/templates/activities` folder with the contents of the ZIP file.

You may need to restart Eclipse with the `-clean` option for it to work.

Comment: +1 for explaining the cause of this problem, thx. By the way, this answer would be more complete if you add a direct link to the file need to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From Eclipse go to Help > Check for updates and install any of the updates that Eclipse shows.

Once you update the SDK components you always usually need to update the Eclipse plugins as well.

Comment: This made no difference for me.

Comment: Run the SDK manager again and ensure everything is up to date, and run the eclipse updater again. Maybe https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149 will also help

Answer (score 0):

I started facing the same issue yesterday when I upgraded to the latest Android SDK Tools (22.2). So I reverted back the changes and am now using Android SDK Tool (22.0.5) and it works fine.

Try downgrading Android SDK Tools.