# Eclipse reports rendering library more recent than ADT plug-in

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

On a new Android SDK installation, the Eclipse Graphical Layout is blank, rather than showing the rendering of the layout. Eclipse displays this message:

> This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in.

The bug report *[Eclipse reports rendering library more recent than ADT plug-in](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60180)* lists the steps to reproduce. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 511, accepted):

1. Click **Help > Install New Software**.
2. In the **Work with** field, enter: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
3. Select **Developer Tools / Android Development Tools**.
4. Click **Next** and complete the wizard.

Comment: Do not use SDK Manager. Do the steps above for it to work. Most (like me) confuse between SDK Manager and Install New Software

Comment: Also it's better to enter the `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` url manually rather than use the possible existing version without `https`. Might result in repository not found errors.

Comment: +1. sometimes i wonder how does the world work before google and stackoverflow. (Am I somehow supposed to innately know those steps and the url.)

Comment: For me it show nothing to update, but still layout doesn't render and showing the same message... any idea?

Comment: I am getting this error `An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826`

Comment: Update: I solved my problem by unchecking `Contact all update sites during install to find required software`

Comment: i prefer the quicker Shubh's solution. Updating Eclipse often caused me problems and made me loose a lot of time

Comment: `https` did not work, for me this worked - `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

Comment: "All items are installed" thats why no next button appears!

Comment: Here I was blaming myself when it was Google's fault.

Comment: `Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, May take a while: 1/15` ... and then when finished: `Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.`

Comment: Also uncheck `contact all update sites during install to find required software`

Comment: After ADT 23.7 there is no update for ADT, google stopped supporting eclipse as their platform. now we will be unable to use adt from android version 6

Comment: To the people saying that they can't click the `Next` button in the Install window, I suggest unchecking the box that says `Hide items that are already installed`

Answer (score 340):

**Change android version while rendering layout.**

[image]

Change in API version 18 to 17 work for me.

**Edit:** Solution worked for Android Studio too.

Comment: This is a good solution if you don't want to update Eclipse/ADT.  The downside is your layout will not be rendered on the latest tools, which is not a big deal.  I recommend trying it before updating Eclipse/ADT as it is very quick to try and would confirm that updating would also fix the problem.

Comment: very quick to try and would confirm that updating would also fix the problem

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me ...updating ADT is telling me there are dependancy conflicts...just hate eclipse and +5 for you

Comment: if it still not working ,then open up SDK manager and install a lower api sdk , and restart eclipse

Comment: This looks more like a workaround than a solution, IMHO.

Comment: This solution coupled with the update from above by Edward Brey worked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: This is the actual problem!

Comment: I have the latest ADT and still it seems that rendering the API `22: Android M (Preview)` is not supported by ADT (API `22: Android 5.1.1` renders ok). Google tells the Android Studio is the official tool, and not Eclipse with ADT. Is the solution to migrate to Android Studio?

Comment: I checked with Studio and Eclipse both and it worked great. What is min API version update you have in you SDK. You can go either of lower version then 22.

Comment: Yoooo!!! After spending 2 hour. Finally it worked just by changing rendering layout. Thanks man.

Comment: @fishjd - Updating didn't fix the problem for me (possible because the editor was defaulting to the 'developer preview' SDK, and there's not a corresponding ADT update available through the Eclipse site yet?), but this answer did.

Answer (score 18):

The Reason for Warning is your using Old ADT (Android development tools),
  so Update your ADT by following the procedures below

Procedure 1:

1. Inside Eclipse  Click Help  menu
2. Choose Check for Updates
3. It will show Required Updates in that window choose All options using Check box or     else choose ADT Updated.

[image]

Procedure 2:

Click Help > Install New Software.
   In the Work with field, enter: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
   Select Developer Tools / Android Development Tools.
   Click Next and complete the wizard.

Comment: Interestingly, the check for updates kept failing on some egit crap that got left behind, but the install new worked great.

Comment: +1 I had similar experience as @WilliamT.Mallard.   Check for updates said everything was up to date.  Install New worked.

Answer (score 1):

Am i change API version **17, 19, 21, & 23** in xml layoutside

&&

Updated **Android Development Tools** ***23.0.7***  but still can't render layout proper so am i updated **Android DDMS** ***23.0.7*** it's works perfect..!!!

Answer (score -2):

Please try once uninstalling from **Help-->Installation details**

and try again installing using http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score -10):

Change the Target version to new updates you have. Otherwise, change what SDK version you have in the Android manifest file.

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```