# ADT plug-in update fails to install

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Eclipse SDK Juno v4.2.2 with ADT v22.2.0v201309112335-822323. The message in Eclipse reads:

**The version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in.**

Attempted update numerous times, same results:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:

```
(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.2.0.v201309112335--822323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.2.0.v201309112335--822323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.2.0.v201309112335--822323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.2.0.v201309112335--822323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.8.0.v20130125-0826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks,1.2.200.v201203141800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui,1.2.201.v201208292200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore,1.2.201.v201301092200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ui,1.0.201.v201208241600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.300.v201111030424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets,1.2.200.v201204260225
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver,1.2.0.v201203071939
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.core,1.1.600.v201205171933
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui,1.0.700.v201203081826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.cache,1.0.600.v201203071939
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.702.v201301241617
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.3.102.v201301162301
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.standard.schemas,1.0.501.v201301091615
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.402.v201212031633
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui,1.2.400.v201204260100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.702.v201301101836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui,1.1.302.v201301172222
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core,1.1.700.v201204102147
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui,1.2.500.v201203081826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.2.0.v201309112335--822323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.2.0.v201309112335--822323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.2.0.v201309112335--822323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature,3.4.2.v201212051536-7B7EFMVF7RZHOkJkNwS4TV
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature,3.4.2.v201212051536-7C7AFeFEdhOaweLhCnQfylKlOxT5UW
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.4.2.v201211061806-7C7OFm9F7RZHQVHiOz-P0Up
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.4.2.v201211061806-7H7GFeJDxumUrsn5qkiQgOEhsz0p60HAmPyU6VX
```

None of the ADT updates will install - all give similar error messages.

Thannk you.

Comment: This may help you:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852983/eclipse-reports-rendering-library-more-recent-than-adt-plug-in

Answer (score 19):

Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”

Comment: I can confirm this works. I just used this method to update to the Sept 2013 ADT

Answer (score 7):

This is taken directly from: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

These are the steps I followed with the same issue, and it corrected it immediately.

- Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
- Click Add, in the top-right corner.
- In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- Click OK.

If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).

- In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
- In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
- Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.

When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Update the plugin offline. follow the steps given on the [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best solution, but what I have figured out is that the errors **"The version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in."**  and the inablility to update ADT are due to a workspace problem. By renaming the workspace to a ".old", Eclipse started fine, and was able to update without problems. However, I cannot revert to the original workspace as Eclipse seizes on start-up after switching. Deleting the new empty workspace again allowed start-up. I will figure out how to recover my projects, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to selected android M(Preview) version to un-select and select 5.1.1.
I hope to solve your problem.