# how do I update ADT plugin in Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-2.1

My Android SDK is refusing to render activity_main.xml in a GUI and shows me this message:

[image]

I went to Help > Check for Updates but it says there no updates
How do I get the GUI for activity_main.xml back?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852983/eclipse-reports-rendering-library-more-recent-than-adt-plug-in any helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the adt from here

You might need to update the software source for your adt update

Go to `eclipse > help > Check for updates.`

It should list the latest update of adt. If it is not working try this

go to `eclipse > help > Install new software`

Click on add

add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

give it any name.

It will list the updates available- which should ideally be adt 20.xx

Eclipse will restart and hopefully everything should work fine for you.