# eclipse error with plugins after update

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I encountered a problem with

```
This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in.
Please update ADT plug-in
```

i tried this as learned from: [Eclipse reports rendering library more recent than ADT plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852983/eclipse-reports-rendering-library-more-recent-than-adt-plug-in)

```
1. Click Help > Install New Software.
2. In the Work with field, enter: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3. Select Developer Tools / Android Development Tools.
4. Click Next and complete the wizard.
```

new problem:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.java.lang.NullPointerException
```

i tried this on windows cmd ( again through some stackoverflow forums):

```
eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState
```

But i have not got any solution

This is new message:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.com/android/utils/SparseArray
```

Error log has a lot of messages like:

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
```

It shows whenever i try to open any layout xml file

after reverting ( as suggested by aumand) i am back on my first problem again with this msg on graphical layout of xml files ( i dont remember the exact words, but i think issue is something like >>>library i am using is 4.1.2 and the taget has loaded 4.4)

```
This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in.
```

Plz help guyz..

Comment: Not a real solution but maybe a workaround:
If "something" went wrong during your update process, then you may revert your eclipse installation to a previous version. This can (depending on your eclipse version) usually be done by entering Help > About Eclipse > Installation details > {Select a version before your update} > Revert

Comment: I think Once you need to reinstall the eclipse and reinstall...

Comment: during this updation, i just selected and updated android development tools

Comment: trying to revert this as aumand said

Comment: after reverting, i am back on my first problem again with this msg on graphical layout of xml files ( i dont remember the exact words, but i think issue is something like >>>library i am using is 4.1.2 and the taget has loaded 4.4)>>>>> This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in.$$$$ but i dont know the solution

Comment: Try `Help->Check for Updates` once and check if any updates are displayed.

Comment: there is a long list of updates, but i don't want to mess with it again as i mentioned in my ques, what happened when i updated only one of them

Comment: is it the only solution, do i need to update all of them

Comment: I had "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.com/android/utils/SparseArray" when I just updated Android development Tools. I solved this problem after I installed rest of the updates: Android DDMS, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android Traceview, Tracer for OpengGL ES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your DDMS and ADT to latest version form Help>Check For Updates. this solved my problem!

Comment: I had updated Android Developer Tools (ADT) without updating Android DDMS. Updating DDMS solved my issue. The error messages is horribly misleading!

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the [Eclipse/ADT bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from google.  Eclipse won't need any updates, and you will only need to run the SDK manager to check for a few updates and install any previous versions you want.

I did this after my initial Eclipse install, with ADT added later, decided it didn't want to run any more (crash on startup).  The package works better than the previous stuff, even though they were both up to date.

You can also copy anything from your previous sdk folder to the new one, so you don't have to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Download Eclipse ADT Bundle its best , go here and download it http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and you can run sdk manager to check for any kind of updates.