# Android app crashing only in google nexus 7 running android 4.4.2 - kitkat

Tags: android, crash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-7

I am developing a android tab application and I have tested in 10 and 7 inch emulators running android 4.0.3 which is Ice Cream Sand-witch. When I try to run the same application on google galaxy nexus 7, the app crashes at launch. I have also included following lines in the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I think there is no issue with my folder structure (drawables and layout folders):

[image: res folder structure]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the stack trace of the crash from logcat.

Comment: I run the apk only. So I do not have a way to get the stack trace.

Comment: Still, logcat will most likely have a hint of what's going on.  Look at it as the app crashes.

Comment: download app called aLogCat it should record the stacktrace

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the help. I managed to get it working..

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. There were two mistakes that I had done.

1. SDK was not updated to kitkat.
2. Layout files were not included in layouts-sw600 (portrait).

Steps I took:

- Updated the SDK to kitkat.
- Then folowed [Eclipse reports rendering library more recent than ADT plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852983/eclipse-reports-rendering-library-more-recent-than-adt-plug-in) stpe
- Created a nexus 7 emulator running kitkat.
- Then found the bug.