# How can I update my ADT plug-in?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

How I can update my ADT plug-in when I change the API level from 17 to 19 I get this message: "This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in".

How can I update my ADT plug-in ?!

I want to make an API 19 but the current API 17 no problem

> [image]

Comment: see this link for answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18852984/2675669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps,

- Go to eclipse
- Select Help Menu
- Select Check for Install new updates
- A dialog box like below will appear

> [image]

- Write the url and it will load the available updates
- Select the option , click on next.
- Done

If this doesnt work then following steps,

- Open your Android SDK Manager like below,

> [image]

- Select both the options "Android SDK Tools" & "Android Platform-tools" and updated them.

Comment: i try that . response is no update is found

Comment: @JeremiahMe does it shows the second red circle check boxes to you ?

Comment: no just a dialog box that says no update is found

Comment: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826

Comment: i got this error whats the problem?

Comment: please see the picture of my sdk manager i just update it from my question .

Comment: @JeremiahMe what Operating system you are using  ?

Comment: windows 8 pro. it is ok to use windows 8?

Comment: @JeremiahMe I havent check it with windows 8 till

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48648/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-jeremiah-me)

Comment: but when i choose API 17 it all good but when i put to API 19 i got those message.  by the way thanks .

Answer (score 0):

The Reason for Warning is your using Old ADT (Android development tools),
  so Update your ADT by following the procedures below

**Procedure 1:**

1. Inside Eclipse  Click Help  menu
2. Choose Check for Updates
3. It will show Required Updates in that window choose All options using Check box or     else choose ADT Updated.

[image]

**Procedure 2:**

> - Click Help > Install New Software.
> - In the Work with field, enter:
>     https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
> - Select Developer Tools /  Android Development Tools.
> - Click Next and complete the wizard.