# Why my adt can't preview the xml

Tags: xml, android-layout, eclipse-adt

The version of my adt is 23.0.7.2120684 and I can't preview the res/layout/activity_main.xml.It show me the error is that "the version of library is more rencet than your version of adt".And I use Android6.0(api23).

Comment: Make sure you installed all needed sdk components.. if you dont know which to install and which not.. prefer installing all of them.

Comment: Its very common in eclipse do android version down [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852983/eclipse-reports-rendering-library-more-recent-than-adt-plug-in)