# Eclipse cannot create new Android Application Project after updating the Android SDK Tools

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-sdk-tools

today i update the android SDK Tools to rev22.2

and then i can't create new android application project.

it tells me that the Android Support library is either not installed or need to update.

but ver.18 is the newest version of Android Support library!

i pressed the Install/Upgrade button but nothing happened.

i used Android SDK manager tried to uninstall and install the android support library again, restart the Eclipse, restart the computer, but all these can't fix the situation.

now i don't know what to do...

the version of Eclipse is Kepler ver.4.3.0

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/adt-22-2-new-app-wizard-unsupported-template-dependency-upgrade-your-android-e/18849033

Answer (score 2):

Yes , I had the same problem . You need to update your ADT version

Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
Click Add, in the top-right corner.
In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: I have updated my eclipse kepler ADT too but still im not able to create new android project

Comment: I encountered this problem today. Now I cant make a new android project! (doesn't exist in menu anymore). also cant run my code as an android application. It seems there is no connection between eclipse and android libraries now.
Please help!