# Eclipse, New Android Application Install/upgrade library not working

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm new to android development. I'm following a guide presently. When i click on New Android application and set the application name, etc. etc, in the last step (Update support library files), I get stuck. Now initially my support library version was not up to date. So I looked up some solutions. I did what was advised. I went to my SDK manager and deleted the Support library itself. Then when I tried to create a new android application again, i reached the final step once again. In that step, I clicked "Install/Upgrade". But nothing happened. So i went back into SDK manager and installed it again manually. I hit "Check again" in eclipse. It said 
"Required Version : 
 Installed Version : 18"

But the finish button never get's highlighted and the "Install/Upgrade" button doesn't work. I tried uninstalling and re-installing the support library again and again. But no matter what i do, the "Install/Upgrade" button never works right and neither does my finish button get highlighted.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Regards

Comment: Maybe you are forgetting to check the box saying "I agree...

Comment: Already tried it. Must be some bug. Tried re-installing library support files multiple times too. Same result. Not able to create a andap

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/adt-22-2-new-app-wizard-unsupported-template-dependency-upgrade-your-android-e/18849033