# cannot create new android project in eclipse after updating sdk

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently I updated the android sdk build-tools. I tried to create a new android project but got a problem. I deleted the android support tools, re-installed it, Reset the Android Preferences(SDK location), clicked the Install/Update button But still no luck.

I entered the following
Minimum Required SDK API 9 Gingerbread
Target SDK: API 18
Compile With : API 18
Theme: Holo light

Following errors occurs at the last.
Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin

This template depends on the Android Support library, which is either not installed, or the template depends on a more recent version than the one you have installed.

Required version:
Installed version: 18

Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: reset adt plugin in eclipse

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADT 22.2 New App Wizard: Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/adt-22-2-new-app-wizard-unsupported-template-dependency-upgrade-your-android-e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem with new adt September update, first update your eclipse adt plugin manually, and then you have to follow this [Link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149#c55)