# Cannot create android application using eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

**NOTE:** I have already fixed this problem.  I used the methods described in a previous question/answer discussion.  Thank you for whoever tagged this as previously answered!
It an be found here: [ADT 22.2 New App Wizard: Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse)

Today I just downloaded and installed Eclipse via the developer.android.com tutorials.  I had almost initiated my first Android Application when I came across this error:

[image: My Error]

I don't understand the error.  It does not specify a required version, and my version is the most up to date version.  Neither the [Install/Upgrade] nor the [Check Again] buttons appear to function.  I have also tried to delete and reinstall the Android Support Library via the SDK Manager multiple times.

Can any one help me? Thanks in advance!

**Note - I do in fact have both the Android Support Library and Android 4.3 installed:**

[image: Proof of Installation]

**Edited to add picture and note**

Comment: Try cleaning your project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues when create new android application project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you create your project? Steps: New -> Android Application Project? If you've done this, you should check whether you have installed "Android 4.3" and "Extras->Android Support Library" in Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Your guess of how I started my new project was correct.  I looked in the SDK Manager to verify that I do have Android 4.3 installed, while the problem still persists.

Comment: did you download the whole [android SDK bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), or install eclipse and ADT separately?

Comment: I downloaded a zip file from the developer.android.com website.  Within it is Eclipse + ADT plugin, Android SDK Tools, Android Platform-tools, the latest Android platform, and the latest Android system for an emulator

Comment: I suppose now that I installed eclipse from the eclipse website, then downloaded the bundle, ran eclipse from the bundle, tried to start a new project, then came across the error, then verified that I had the Library and Android 4.3 installed.  Perhaps this order of events was a better answer to your question?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter. Although you downloaded an eclipse from eclipse website, you didn't run it.

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent helping.  An answer has already been found for my question previously, so I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: so what's the answer？ could you share?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Android SDK Manager, then download the required Android version, in your case, version 18 which is Android 4.3.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I looked in the SDK Manager to verify that I do have Android 4.3 installed. Unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project -> properties -> Android -> select a platform like 4.0

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have installed android 4.3 sdk(API level 18).
Please open eclipse->windows->android sdk manager  and make sure your android 4.3(API 18) status is installed.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I looked in the SDK Manager to verify that I do have Android 4.3 installed. Unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Download from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-windows.zip, unzip it and replace the /tools folder with this one to downgrade the sdk tools. There's a bug in version 22.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but someone found that this is a duplicate.  I replaced my sdk/tools/templates/activities folder with a more up-to-date one, which resulted in success.  The steps and files can be found here:

([ADT 22.2 New App Wizard: Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse))

Thank you for all who took time to try and answer my questions.  It is much appreciated!