# Mac Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, sdk, adt

I have a mac and downloaded the bundle just yesterday.

I am trying to create an android project but keep getting this error:
Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin

I have tried everything suggested that I saw with the exception of deleting SDK & ADT and using an old version. Any suggestions ?

- all plugins are "up-to-date" according to SDK manager
  *I tried replacing the tools folder with a new, bug free tools folder but that didn't seem to work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues when create new android application project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: I have already posted solution [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your sdk/tools/templates/activities folder with the contents of this zip should resolve this issue.

[Activities Zip](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=601490055000&name=activities.zip&token=tNG-jL5v1K1cnbgIbRyPgrXtRF8:1379484316034)

Thanks