# adt, Install dependencies doesnt work

Tags: android, dependencies, installation, adt

After updated my ADT to v22.2.0-822323 and sdk tools ver 18, I am not able to create new Project through Project wizard from Eclipse.

In the project wizard I have reached upto Install Dependencies screen, where "Next" and "Finish" buttons are disabled. I have tried to click "Install/Upgrade" button but nothing happens. So I try to reinstall adt bundle and android support library. but same problem occured. 
In my project wizard' INstall Dependencies, I can see Installed version : 18, but there is no information about required version.

Could anybody please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you install with version 8 as well? I just checked my system and it requires version 8.

Comment: You mean that install android support library version8? not 18?

Comment: Yep. Just checked again. Required version is 8.

Comment: I found direct link for support library rev8, deleted rev 18 and installed rev8. but nothing changed. I can see that  in my window required version with empty space, and installed version is 8. no response when i click the update button.

Comment: Also, what SDKs have you installed? and what targeting and theme have you selected?

Comment: android sdk tools rev 22.2, platform tools 18.01, build tools 18.1,18.01,17 all component of Android4.3(API18), android support repository rev 2. In Project Wizard, target SDK is api18, compile with api 18. theme? is Holo light with dark action bar

Comment: Great, after update, I'm stuck in a similar situation. :( Looks like a bug in eclipse plugin/support library. Keep an eye open for eclipse plugin update from android. In the meantime, you could download sample projects to start off.

Comment: ooh... :(  thanks for your helps. and I feel sorry to hear that..

Comment: I'm just living the same situation!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse/18849033

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149) at comment #7. Just update the tools directory to save your time. I don't know if the official solution will take too much time.