# Not able to create new Android project using ADT version 22.2

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

Iam using upgraded version of ADT only but Adt is creating problem while creating new project,not able to create new Activity also

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues when create new android application project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/issues-when-create-new-android-application-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: i heared that there is a problem with api 18 with eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.2-windows.zip, unzip it and replace the /tools folder with this one to downgrade the sdk tools. There's a bug in version 22.2.

For Mac http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.2-macosx.zip

For Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.2-linux.zip

Comment: replaced tools with link you provided but even after replacing facing same problem

Comment: did you try restarting your eclipse after that.

Comment: It should work then....you can try out with this link as well https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149#c55

Comment: You probably meant to link to 22.0 and not 22.2 as the latter is exactly the problematic version.

Comment: But as I recall, the same kind of problem existed in 22.0

Comment: Re-installed and then replaced tools with  [link]( http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.2-windows.zip,)  now it is working

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing Android Eclipse Plug-in

Comment: even after re-installing also same problem

Answer (score 0):

Read this page http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

do the offline upgrade.