# Install dependencies. Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-manager

I get this error message:

> Install dependencies.  Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin.

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6YQw.png)

Comment: The error is: Your ADT plugin is not updated. Go to the SDK Manager (Windows -> SDK Manager) and update it.

Answer (score 7):

Download from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-windows.zip, unzip it and replace the /tools folder with this one to downgrade the sdk tools. There's a bug in version 22.

For Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-linux.zip

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/adt-22-2-new-app-wizard-unsupported-template-dependency-upgrade-your-android-e/18849033#18849033    thanks for this link...

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the new [ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html) September 2013 update. First update your [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) ADT plugin manually, and then you have to follow [#55 in *Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin*](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149#c55).