# android adt support library

Tags: android, eclipse

Now in Eclipse i can not make a new project with default **BlankActivity** implemented in it.

I have downloaded ADT bundle my os is windows 8(32-bit)
In the new project dialog i am sticking at the last screen which mention that there is **"Install Dependencies"** of **`android support library revision 8 required`** for this.

I **already** have **revision 9** installed in SDK. I also clicked "**Install/Upgrade**" button but nothing happened.
I haave tried uninstall libraries and then install by clicking on **Install/upgrade** but it not worked for me as buttons are not doing anything on clicking.

Below is screenshot of that dialog
![enter image description here][1]

```
I know that we can create blank project by unchecking 
CreateActivity option, but i want to make project with BlankActivity
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADT 22.2 New App Wizard: Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/adt-22-2-new-app-wizard-unsupported-template-dependency-upgrade-your-android-e)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Go to the Android SDK folder (usually here : C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ )  and execute the SDK Manager.exe, you will see if there is updates to the Android SDK Tools and Android SDK platform-tools, install the updates and restart eclipse.