# Eclipse - Cannot create new Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I have recently installed the latest version of Eclipse and followed the instructions on the Android website to install the ADT Plugin.

Using the SDK Manager I installed all of the possible Android SDK's as seen here:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Now when I create a new Android Application Project, and follow through the prompts.. I get this error:

[image]

Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin.
I looked at a few other answers, and tried renaming folders from Support to Compatability etc, but nothing has worked so far.

I decided to start using eclipse after Android Studio had too many bugs to work with. I am working on the latest Mac OSX 10.8.3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADT 22.2 New App Wizard: Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839428/adt-22-2-new-app-wizard-unsupported-template-dependency-upgrade-your-android-e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download the eclipse with the ADT bundle and SDK from the android developers website [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) i think things would have been much easier

Comment: Thanks. Made things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the correct path to your SDK folder. Go to Eclipse-> Preferences-> Android and check you are pointing to the right SDK folder.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it is referencing the right SDK folder, and the system itself shows that the installed version is 18.